# Globally Reuse ActiveRecord Queries across Models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization

Not sure how to word the question concisely :).

I have say 20 Posts per page, and each Post has 3-5 tags.  If I show all the tags in the sidebar (`Tag.all.each...`), then is there any way to have a call to `post.tags` not query the database and just use the tags found from `Tag.all`?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

This is how you might use it:

```
# posts_controller.rb
posts = Post.all

# posts/index.html.haml
- posts.each do |post|
  render :partial => "posts/item", :locals => {:post => post}

# posts/_item.html.haml
- post.tags.each do |tag|
  %li
    %a{:href => "/tags/#{tag.name}"}= tag.name.titleize
```

I know about the following optimizations already:

1. Rendering partials using `:collection`
2. Eager loading with `Post.first(:include => [:tags])`

I'm wondering though, if I use `Tag.all` in my `shared/_sidebar.haml` template, is there anyway to reuse the result from that query in the `post.tags` calls?

Comment: Is a post an Article? Please describe what you're trying to accomplish, because it's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tag_ids` method on a `Post` instance.

In your controller create the tag hash. Better still cache the tag hash.

Add this to your `application_controller.rb`.

```
def all_tags
  @all_tags ||=Rails.cache.fetch('Tag.all', :expire_in => 15.minutes)){ Tag.all }
  # without caching
  #@all_tags ||= Tag.all
end


def all_tags_hash
  @all_tags_hash ||= all_tags.inject({}){|hash, tag| hash[tag.id]=tag;hash}
end

def all_tags_by_ids ids
  ids ||= []
  ids = ids.split(",").map{|str| str.to_i} if ids.is_a?(string)
  all_tags_hash.values_at(*ids)
end
helper_method :all_tags, :all_tags_hash, :all_tags_by_id
```

Now your partial can be rewritten as

```
# posts/_item.html.haml
- all_tags_by_ids(post.tag_ids).each do |tag|
  %li
    %a{:href => "/tags/#{tag.name}"}= tag.name.titleize
```

My solution caches the `Tag` models for 15 minutes. Make sure you add an observer/filter on Tag model to invalidate/update the cache during create/update/delete.

In your `config\environment.rb`

```
config.active_record.observers = :tag_observer
```

Add a `tag_observer.rb` file to your `app\models` directory.

```
class TagObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  def after_save(tag)
    update_tags_cache(tag)
  end

  def after_destroy(tag)
    update_tags_cache(tag, false)
  end

  def update_tags_cache(tag, update=true)
    tags = Rails.cache.fetch('Tag.all') || []
    tags.delete_if{|t| t.id == tag.id}
    tags << tag if update
    Rails.cache.write('Tag.all', tags, :expire_in => 15.minutes)
  end
end
```

Note: Same solution will work with out the cache also.

This solution still requires you to query the `tags` table for `Tag` ids. You can further optimize by storing tag ids as a comma separated string in the `Post` model(apart from storing it in `post_tags` table).

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :post_tags

  # add a new string column called tag_ids_str to the `posts` table.
end

class PostTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
  after_save :update_tag_ids_str
  after_destroy :update_tag_ids_str

  def update_tag_ids_str    
    post.tag_ids_str = post.tag_ids.join(",")
    post.save
  end
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :posts, :through => :post_tags
end
```

Now your partial can be rewritten as

```
# posts/_item.html.haml
- all_tags_by_ids(post.tag_ids_str).each do |tag|
  %li
    %a{:href => "/tags/#{tag.name}"}= tag.name.titleize
```